# Can I have a more example of FileAttribute?

Tags: java, io, nio

Basically in the `Files.createFile(Path fileName, FileAttribute<?>... attrs );` there is the possibility to insert a series of attributes. I am aware of the following possibility:

```
Path path = Paths.get(path...);//the file path


PosixFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(path,PosixFileAttributes.class);
Set<PosixFilePermission> permissions = attr.permissions();
FileAttribute<Set<PosixFilePermission>> attra 
                            = PosixFilePermissions.asFileAttribute(permissions);
Files.createFile(path,attra);
```

Do you know any other real life application of the `createFile()` method? And with other application I mean other attributes passed as a FileAttribute parameter other than a set of PosixFilePermission? What are other "passable" FileAttribute parameter that I can use to create a new file with `File.createFile(path, attr);` ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, the Access Control Lists (ACL) attributes.**

See [Java 7 Documentation for AclFileAttributeView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/AclFileAttributeView.html) for how to use them with `createFile` and `createDirectory` methods.

Comment: cheers, I am not using windows so does not really matter to me but still it's the only answer  and it's actually true. So tnx for responding best response

Comment: If you run GNU/Linux it still does! ACL is implemented in GNU/Linux for quite long now. It is just rarely used. See `man acl` and commands `getfacl`, `setfacl`.

Comment: well when I run in Java jdk7 on my ubuntu 11.10 this method FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault(); Set<String> supportedOnes = fs.supportedFileAttributeViews(); I do not see in the list AclFileAttributeview

Comment: Right, this facility in Java 7 does not work with GNU/Linux ACL.